# Perl's NET:SSH2 local socket

Tags: linux, perl, ssh, routes, ip

I have two interfaces on my machine eth0 - 172.16.4.70 and eth0:1 - 172.16.4.71
The default behaviour of NET:SSH2 is to create connection from eth0. How can I make the script to use my floating IP in eth0:1?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

On Linux, you have `SO_BINDTODEVICE` available as an option for `setsockopt()`. I haven't tried but [this](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=251477) should be relevant.

Once you have an `IO::Socket::INET` object set up, bound to the correct network device and just before connecting it, you can pass it to Net::SSH2's `connect()`.

Caveat: I've done this in C but never in Perl; this is just from skimming the docs.